# R: Calculate distance between first and current row of grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, distance, tidyverse, tidyr

I need to calculate the Euclidean distance between the first and current row in a dataframe. Each row is keyed by (group, month) and has a list of values. In the toy example below the key is c(month, student) and the values are in c(A, B). I want to create a distance column C, that's equal to sqrt((A_i-A_1)^2 + (B_i - B_1)^2).

So far I managed to spread my data and pull each group's first values into new columns. While I could create the formula by hand in the toy example, in my actual data I have very many columns instead of just 2. I believe I could create the squared differences within the mutate_all, and then do a row sum and take the square root of that, but no luck so far.

```
df <- data.frame(month=rep(1:3,2),
                 student=rep(c("Amy", "Bob"), each=3),
                 A=c(9, 6, 6, 8, 6, 9),
                 B=c(6, 2, 8, 5, 6, 7))

# Pull in each column's first values for each group
df %>% 
  group_by(student) %>% 
  mutate_all(list(first = first)) %>% 
# TODO: Calculate the distance, i.e. SQRT(sum_i[(x_i - x_1)^2]).

#Output:
  month student     A     B month_first A_first B_first
1     1 Amy         9     6           1       9       6
2     2 Amy         6     2           1       9       6
...
```

Desired output:

```
#Output:
  month student     A     B month_first A_first B_first dist_from_first
1     1 Amy         9     6           1       9       6    0
2     2 Amy         6     2           1       9       6    5
...
```

Comment: can you write out A and B and dist_from_first are calculated in your desired output example

Comment: dist_from_first is the distance between the Row's values and the Row's corresponding group's first Row's values. I.e. Sqrt((9-9)^2 + (6-6)^2) = 0, Sqrt((9-6)^2+(6-2)^2) = Sqrt(25)=5.

Comment: euc_dist <- function(x0,x1,y0,y1) sqrt((x0-x1)^2+(y0-y1)^2) and ... %>%   mutate(dist_from_first = euc_dist(A_first,A,B_first,B))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: added alternative formulation using a join.** I expect that approach will be much faster for a very wide data frame with many columns to compare.

*Approach 1:* To get euclidean distance for a large number of columns, one way is to rearrange the data so each row shows one month, one student, and one original column (e.g. A or B in the OP), but then two columns representing current month value and first value. Then we can square the difference, and group across all columns to get the euclidean distance, aka root-mean-squared / RMS for each student-month.

```
  library(tidyverse)
  df %>% 
    group_by(student) %>% 
    mutate_all(list(first = first)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
  # gather into long form; make col show variant, col2 show orig column
  gather(col, val, -c(student, month, month_first)) %>%
  mutate(col2 = col %>% str_remove("_first")) %>% 
  mutate(col = if_else(col %>% str_ends("_first"),
                        "first",
                        "comparison")) %>% 
  spread(col, val) %>% 
  mutate(square_dif = (comparison - first)^2) %>%
  group_by(student, month) %>%
  summarize(RMS = sqrt(sum(square_dif)))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   student [2]
  student month   RMS
  <fct>   <int> <dbl>
1 Amy         1  0   
2 Amy         2  5   
3 Amy         3  3.61
4 Bob         1  0   
5 Bob         2  2.24
6 Bob         3  2.24
```

*Approach 2.* Here, a long version of the data is joined to a version that is just the earliest month for each student.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_long <- gather(df, col, val, -c(month, student))
df_long %>% left_join(df_long %>% 
              group_by(student) %>%
              top_n(-1, wt = month) %>%
              rename(first_val = val) %>% 
              select(-month),
            by = c("student", "col")) %>%
  mutate(square_dif = (val - first_val)^2) %>%
  group_by( student, month) %>%
  summarize(RMS = sqrt(sum(square_dif)))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   student [2]
  student month   RMS
  <fct>   <int> <dbl>
1 Amy         1  0   
2 Amy         2  5   
3 Amy         3  3.61
4 Bob         1  0   
5 Bob         2  2.24
6 Bob         3  2.24
```

Comment: Approach 1 is perfect! It made me realize that going with long format is actually easier than with wide format in this case. Thank you!

Comment: Just note if his data is wide with columns A,B,C,D, etc., that this would summarize all columns. Meaning the RMS would be ```sqrt(A_sq_diff + B_sq_diff+C_sq_diff+D_sq_dff)```.

Comment: I believe that is what is required. The euclidean distance for each row should be `sqrt(Adif^2 + Bdif^2 + Cdif^2 + Ddif^2 +....)`.

Comment: But that would go into n dimensions, right? In other words, column D would mean a 4 dimensional distance. I guess I thought OP meant the distance for each two groups of columns.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using compact `dplyr` code.  This can be used for any number of columns

```
df %>% 
  select(-month) %>%
  group_by(student) %>% 
  mutate_each(function(x) (first(x) - x)^2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(euc.dist = sqrt(rowSums(select(., -1))))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  student     A     B euc.dist
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Amy         0     0     0   
2 Amy         9    16     5   
3 Amy         9     4     3.61
4 Bob         0     0     0   
5 Bob         4     1     2.24
6 Bob         1     4     2.24
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `mutate_all` call, it'd be easier to directly calculate the `dist_from_first`. The only thing I'm unclear about is whether month should be included in the `group_by()` statement.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(month=rep(1:3,2),
                 student=rep(c("Amy", "Bob"), each=3),
                 A=c(9, 6, 6, 8, 6, 9),
                 B=c(6, 2, 8, 5, 6, 7))

df%>%
  group_by(student)%>%
  mutate(dist_from_first = sqrt((A - first(A))^2 + (B - first(B))^2))%>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  month student     A     B dist_from_first
#  <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#1     1 Amy         9     6            0   
#2     2 Amy         6     2            5   
#3     3 Amy         6     8            3.61
#4     1 Bob         8     5            0   
#5     2 Bob         6     6            2.24
#6     3 Bob         9     7            2.24
```

Comment: Yes, this is how you could do it with a few columns where you can just write them all up - I have several thousand columns to do this for though.

Comment: Can you expand your question? It's unclear what your real dataset looks like.

Comment: Instead of just columns A and B, I have several thousand columns, i.e. A, B, C, D, ... .